# Interest Rate Tree in Matlab

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, finance, actuarial-science

I would like to calibrate a interest rate tree using the optimization tool in matlab. Need some guidance on doing it.

The interest rate tree looks like this:

[image]

How it works:

3.73% = 2.5%*exp(2*0.2)

96.40453 = (0.5*100 + 0.5*100)/(1+3.73%)

94.15801 = (0.5*96.40453+ 0.5*97.56098)/(1+2.50%)

The value of 2.5% is arbitrary and the upper node is obtained by multiplying with an exponential of 2*volatility(here it is 20%).

I need to optimize the problem by varying different values for the lower node.

How do I do this optimization in Matlab?

What I have tried so far?

```
InterestTree{1}(1,1) = 0.03;
size = size(InterestTree,2);
InterestTree{size-1}(1,size-1)= 2.5/100;
InterestTree{size}(2,:) = 100;
InterestTree{size-1}(1,size-2)= (2.5*exp(2*0.2))/100;
InterestTree{size-1}(2,size-1)=(0.5*InterestTree{size}(2,size)+0.5*InterestTree{size}(2,size-1))/(1+InterestTree{size-1}(1,size-1));
j = size-2;
InterestTree{size-1}(2,size-2)=(0.5*InterestTree{size}(2,j+1)+0.5*InterestTree{size}(2,j))/(1+InterestTree{size-1}(1,j));
InterestTree{size-2}(2,size-2)=(0.5*InterestTree{size-1}(2,j+1)+0.5*InterestTree{size-1}(2,j))/(1+InterestTree{size-2}(1,j));
```

New Edit:

```
function [ diff ] = InterestTreeComputation(Interest,DiscountedValue,alpha)
total= size(Interest,1);
n = ceil(0.5*(-1+sqrt(1+8*total)));
DiscountedValue(end:-1:(end-n+1)) = 100;
m=0;
for i=total-n:-1:total-2*n+2
    Interest(i)= (alpha*exp(2^(m)*0.005))/100;
    m = m+1;
end
for j= total-n:-1:1
    columnnumber =ceil(0.5*(-1+sqrt(1+8*j)));
    DiscountedValue(j) = (0.5*DiscountedValue(j+columnnumber)+0.5*DiscountedValue(j+columnnumber+1))/(1+Interest(j));
end
Data = xlsread('InterestData.xlsx');
ActualValue = Data(:,4);
diff = (DiscountedValue(1) - ActualValue(n-1))^2;
end
```

How I call it:

```
clear all;close all;clc;
Interest = [0.0954;0;0];
DiscountedValue =zeros(3,1);
Interest = [Interest; zeros(3,1)];
DiscountedValue = [DiscountedValue; zeros(3,1)];
fhand = @(x)InterestTreeComputation(Interest,DiscountedValue,x);
x0 = 2.5;
x_optimal = fminunc(fhand, x0);
```

How do you optimize this function? Is it like this => x = fminunc(@ITree,x0)?

Comment: Can you write out the exact formulation of the optimization problem? It should look something like $\min_x f(x) \,\, \mathrm{s.t.} \,\, g(x) \lt 0$, or something similar.

Comment: how do you do that? I am not sure how to do that? I need the cell InterestTree{1}(1,2) = actualvalue(in this case:93.7129). I don't want to minimize but want it to be equal. Need some guidance on this..

Comment: If you want them to be equal, then you can minimize their absolute difference. For instance, the trivial problem $\min_x \vert y-x \vert$ has the solution $x=y$.

Comment: I will write the code for the optimization and post it tmr and reply when I am done.Can help to check whether it is right?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I have written the function for the interestratetree.. How do u optimize the function that u have written? Need some guidance on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close. I am assuming that your goal is to find the values of `InterestTree` such that some function of it is equal to `actualValue`. (You really need to include this information in your question. Remember that I, or anybody else here, know nothing about the problem other than what you have written. You need to be explicit in what it is you are trying to do. You are much more likely to get effective help that way.)

The first step is to define your cost function. Let $\mathbf{x}$ be `InterestTree` and let $f(\mathbf{x})$ be the function that returns the value `InterestTree{1}(1,2)`. Lastly, let $\beta$ be `actualValue`. We want to find $\mathbf{x}$ such that $f(\mathbf{x}) = \beta$. The error for any estimate of $\mathbf{x}$ will then be $\epsilon(\mathbf{x}) = \vert f(\mathbf{x}) - \beta \vert$. However, the absolute value function is not convex and convexity is a desirable property of cost functions (you can look this up or just trust me). Thus, we will usually want to use the squared error as the cost function. That is, we want to solve

$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}} \vert f(\mathbf{x}) - \beta \vert^2.
$$

So you'll want to change the value of `diff` to

```
diff = (InterestTree{1}(1,2) - actualValue)^2;
```

To solve this problem in Matlab requires that we write a function that will return the value of the cost function given a vector. Thus, you will need to rewrite your `ITree` function so that `InterestTree` is a vector and not a cell array. Once you have done that, define a function handle that you can pass to the optimizer:

```
fhand = @(x)ITree(x, alpha, actualValue, volatility);
```

We are only searching over `x`, so that is the only variable that the optimizer needs to know about. The above function handle lets the optimizer estimate a value for the interest tree (`x` in the above) and get the cost function with `fhand(x)`. Once you have defined this function handle, that last step is to choose an initial estimate of the vector that represents interest tree, `x0`, and carry out the optimization. Two built-in optimizers you can try are

```
x_optimal = fminunc(fhand, x0);
```

or

```
x_optimal = fminsearch(fhand, x0);
```

There are other optimizaers, but start with these and see if they will solve this problem.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help. I have rewritten the code using the vectors. Now it is working, but the accuracy is not good. In excel, I get 6.56 whereas in matlab, i get 6.54. how to improve this?

Comment: Another qn how do I output the values for Interest and DiscountedValue as well? it just outputs optimal value for alpha...

Comment: Code is edited by the way.

Comment: @lakesh Check the value of the exit code from the optimizer to see why it stopped. See the documentation if you don't know what I am talking about. You can specify a value for the termination tolerance to get a more accurate solution if the optimizer is correctly solving the problem. See the `optimoptions()` and `optimset()` functions for details on the available options. You can also try `fminsearch` rather than `fminunc` and see if that improves the answer. Also, read through the examples provided with Matlab, as they should help you understand how to best use the tools.

Comment: @lakesh It's kind of a hack to get other variables out of the optimizer. One options is to print them to file or to the terminal. Another option is to use global variables, which will let you write their values to a location you can read them from afterwards.

Comment: moreover, the value goes to infinity sometimes. it is weird. I tried using x_optimal = fminbnd(fhand,0,10); where i restrict the values of x to be positive and between 0 to 10. but i still get huge numbers...

Comment: @lakesh Sorry, but I am not familiar enough with the problem to know about its stability. Some cost surfaces are very well behaved and will let you start anywhere and get the correct answer. Other problems have very unstable cost surfaces that require you to give a fairly accurate initial estimate in order to converge to the correct solution. You can try moving `x0` closer/farther from the known solution and see what happens. It might also be a programming error on your part. I can't really say.

Comment: why is it when i give the range for the variable, it still goes out of that range? I clearly state the range of 0 to 10 in fminbnd(fhand,0,10);

Comment: @lakesh That should be impossible. I'd guess that the error is on your part. Make sure that your function meets the requirements of `fminbnd()`.

Comment: Seriously need your help. not sure where the problem is... I can put the actual data in for you to try as well.

Comment: @lakesh I aim to help, but am a busy man and cannot promise anything. The best source of help for you will without out a doubt be the Matlab documentation and a search engine. Work through the examples and understand what it is you are trying to do and how the functions work. Know what type of minimization is being used and whether or not it is appropriate for your problem. Also, make sure that your problem is amenable to being solved through minimization in the first place -- not all problems are. If it's not, then all of this effort and time will have been in vain.

Comment: I have solved it. Error on the coding part. Coding logic mistake. Thanks a lot and learned a lot on optimization.

Comment: @lakesh Glad to hear it. Best of luck to you.